# How can I profile the performance effects of pointer aliasing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, profiling, visual-studio-2013

My code uses a lot of repetitive and largely algebraic operations that are suitable for MATLAB/FORTRAN style vector operations.

I have been considering making a switch to std::valarray or even Blitz++ to take advantage of this. But before making the switch, how can I profile the degree to which one of the main contributors to the performance gap between C++ and FORTRAN - pointer aliasing - is effecting the performance of my code, short of declaring everything with *restrict* and testing the difference.

Does Visual Studio 2012 / 2013 provide some way of achieving this? Maybe a different IDE?

Comment: Is your code using smart pointers? maybe they can be enhanced to detect this?

Comment: @Leeor Most of my performance critical code is c-arrays

Comment: [*This post*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262) might be useful. It is common to assume the code is already so carefully written that only compiler optimization can make it faster, when in fact it actually has huge room for improvement with simple changes, if you only know what those are. After fixing those, pointer aliasing can make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ language is not optimised and will not behave very well doing things math things. For those operation i solely recommend trying to change language or, if you really want staying with c/c++, writing with extreme caution. Different languages are designated to do what they do in best possible way, but its almost never this same thing.

For what i know there is no way of better optimisation most of already existing functions in C/C++, especially non standard packages(boost) because they are suppose to be as simple as possible. Debug packages are also overloaded with debug functions so they are slower, but i also saw some release functions that have security checks like "is object belong to me" or "subscribent out of range check". If this is about atomic functions like aliasing, autopoiters, other pointers types or stuff like that, they just cant be better, and they are made to work as best as its possible.

you can also try telling compiler that you want more compression level, this may speed something if possible, but as i said before, use language that is made for math to do math. Eventually if you can make asm object from fortran or other languages, you can link this file to your code in c/c++.